# Problem with Value That change for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Just run this code in console.
Problem is @notes_before change value after calling method "a.move" for some reasons.
How to fix it and why it happen ?

```
class Slider
  attr_accessor :position
  def initialize(position)
    @position = position
    @notes_before = Array.new
  end

  def move
    @position.each do |note|
      note[0] +=1
    end
    print @notes_before
  end

  def update_pos
    @position.each do |notes|
      @notes_before << notes
    end
    print @notes_before
  end
end

a=Slider.new([[0,0],[0,1]])
a.update_pos
a.move
```

I expect output of @notes_before to be [[0, 0], [0, 1]] after calling a.move but the actual output is [[1, 0], [1, 1]]

Comment: you're first calling `update_pos`, that's why it changes the values.

Comment: `update_pos` sets value of `@notes_before` to [[0, 0], [0, 1]] so it have to be before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the array by reference and not by value. So when the first array changes, the second one changes too because they share the same reference.

What you can do to avoid this problem is :

```
class Slider
  attr_accessor :position
  def initialize(position)
    @position = position
    @notes_before = Array.new
  end

  def move
    @position.each do |note|
      note[0] +=1
    end
    print @notes_before
  end

  def update_pos
    @notes_before = @position.map(&:clone)
    print @notes_before
  end
end

a=Slider.new([[0,0],[0,1]])
a.update_pos
a.move
```

Comment: Thank you thats exacly what I was looking for.